# How can I resize my vbox?

Tags: java

I am trying to resize my vbox using stackpane, and I have tried using setPrefHeight(), setPrefWidth(), and resize(). Please help me.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main_1 extends Application { 
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);

} 
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    StackPane root = new StackPane();

    TextArea textArea = new TextArea();

    VBox vbox = new VBox(textArea);


    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
    vbox.setPrefWidth(scene.getWidth()/2);
    vbox.setPrefHeight(scene.getHeight() * .75);
    vbox.resize(scene.getWidth()/2, scene.getHeight() * .75);

    plus.setTranslateX(scene.getWidth()/2 * .625);
    plus.setTranslateY((scene.getHeight() / 2) * .20);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```